# BroadcastReceiver for handling file by ACTION_SEND?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

Is in possible in Android to create BroadcastReceiver for handling files, shared from other apps?

in manifest i wrote:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<receiver android:name=".modules.file.FileReceiver" >

        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />

            <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

and my FileReceiver file(kotlin):

```
class FileReceiver : WakefulBroadcastReceiver() {

override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
    context?.startService(Intent(context, FileHandlingIntentService::class.java))
}
```

}

BUT I can't send file from file manager to my app, because my app is not in the list of apps which can handle file...
Is it REALLY possible to handle files ONLY in Activity ???
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it right, but in order to receive files from other app you need to create **`Activity`** (**Not `<receiver>` like in your code**) that will handle this files.
Also change the syntax like this:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="pdf/*" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="pdf/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

You can read more [here](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html)

Comment: yeah, i've just made it by activity which running IntentService for file parsing and copying and send only real file path in intent to target activity.
p.s.: send and send_multiple categories can stay in one intent-filter tag)

Answer (score 0):

**This will help to get Data in your app, in my code I will receive image from other apps**

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>


 Intent intent1 = getIntent();
        String action = intent1.getAction();
        String type = intent1.getType();

        if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
            this.handleSend(intent1);
        }

    void handleSend(Intent intent) {
        try {
            Uri imageUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
            imageShare.setImageURI(imageUri);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```